# For real number, Is it true that $sup\{x_i + y_i: i\in I\}=sup\{x_i:i\in I\}+sup\{x_i:i\in I\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory

If $I$ is an indexing set for real numbers so $x_i \text{and} y_i$ are reals.

Is it true that $sup\{x_i + y_i: i\in I\}=sup\{x_i:i\in I\}+sup\{x_i:i\in I\}$?

I thought I need this statement to prove an exercise but I found that I only need the statement:

$sup\{x_i + y_i: i\in I\}\le sup\{x_i:i\in I\}+sup\{x_i:i\in I\}$ which is a straightforward proof by the definition and so the exercise is done but the question whether or not the equlity holds is not answered yet.

My question is, Does the equality always hold? If yes, Could you provide a simple proof,please? if not, Why not give a counterexample and the conditions (if any) under which the equality holds please?

For me, it's intuitively true, for example consider  the special case when the *sup* is the maximum element.

Comment: Let $x_i $ be one on the odd numbers and zero on the even numbers. Let $y_i = 1-x_i$.

Comment: It fails even when $I$ has just two elements.

Comment: @copper.hat, This shows how bad is my intuition! anyway, Could you provide a simple answer to close the question please?

Comment: @MathsLover: I frequently forget my intuition :-).

Comment: @copper.hat , What do you mean by that :) ? Do you mean you don't rely on your intuition?

Comment: @MathsLover: I do, but I forget stuff. A bit like reading a book and realising after the first few pages that you have read this one before. I use intuition as a guide and analysis as my 'rock pro' (as in climbing, not music!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_i$ be one when $i$ is odd and zero otherwise, let $y_i = 1-x_i$, then
$\sup_i x_i = \sup_i y_i = 1$ and $\sup_i(x_i+y_i) = 1$.

The issue is that the indices at which $x_i$ approaches its $\sup$ may be different that the indices at which $y_i$ approaches its $\sup$.